# IOS 5.1 ARC Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, error-handling, uibutton, popover

I have been looking at similar question but couldn't figure it out what is the problem.It seems it should work but it gives me error.

In IOS 5.1 Ipad Stortyboard application I have a right navigation bar item when user click a popover view should open. I had a working popover view but design was not good so I replaced it with a new popover class now it gives me following error

```
-[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa17ba80
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa17ba80'
```

I have tried following functions but none has worked so far. It gives me similar errors when I change the code.

```
- (IBAction)setColorButtonTapped:(id)sender{
- (void)setColorButtonTapped:(id)sender{
- (IBAction)setColorButtonTapped:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
- (void)setColorButtonTapped:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
```

and ofcourse I have changed ti following regarding to **ibaction** or **void**

```
[backButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(setColorButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

here is the code
my.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ColorPickerController.h"

@interface MeetingViewController : UITableViewController<UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,DropDownListDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate,ColorPickerDelegate>{

    UIPopoverController *_popover;
    ColorPickerController *_colorPicker;
    UIPopoverController *_colorPickerPopover;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popover;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ColorPickerController *colorPicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *colorPickerPopover;

- (IBAction)setColorButtonTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

my.m file

```
@synthesize popover = _popover;
@synthesize colorPicker = _colorPicker;
@synthesize colorPickerPopover = _colorPickerPopover;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //gear button on navigation Bar
    UIImage* imageback2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICON - Gear@2x.png"];
    CGRect frameimgback2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);

    UIButton *backButton2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimgback2];
    [backButton2 setBackgroundImage:imageback2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton2 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(setColorButtonTapped:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton2];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn2;

}
#pragma mark ColorPickerDelegate

- (void)colorSelected:(NSString *)color {

    [self.colorPickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Callbacks

- (IBAction)setColorButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (_colorPicker == nil) {
        self.colorPicker = [[ColorPickerController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _colorPicker.delegate = self;
        self.colorPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_colorPicker];
    }
    [self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

utility class
ColorPickerController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ColorPickerDelegate
- (void)colorSelected:(NSString *)color;
@end


@interface ColorPickerController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_colors;
    id<ColorPickerDelegate> __weak _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *colors;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ColorPickerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

utilityclass
ColorPickerController.m

```
#import "ColorPickerController.h"


@implementation ColorPickerController
@synthesize colors = _colors;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

/*
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style])) {
    }
    return self;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(150.0, 140.0);
    self.colors = [NSMutableArray array];
    [_colors addObject:@"Red"];
    [_colors addObject:@"Green"];
    [_colors addObject:@"Blue"];
}




- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_colors count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *color = [_colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = color;

    return cell;
}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_delegate != nil) {
        NSString *color = [_colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_delegate colorSelected:color];
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    self.delegate = nil;
}

@end
```

Help is much appreciated , thanks

Comment: If you use storyboard, why don't take benefits from the segues ?

You could drag a segue from your button to the view you want to appear inside a popover and select "popover". I use this every time

All you have to do is to drag a connection from your button to your view, while holding the "ctrl" key.

Comment: a pop over is like a dropdownlist when user click a list drops down or pop over without changing the current view, how come did you achieve that with segue?

Comment: Like any segues : you simply press and hold down on the "ctrl" key of your keyboard, and drag from your button to your _colorPicker view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a `UIButton` as a customView for a `UIBarButtonItem`. This could be the problem.
I suggest you use `UIBarButtonItem`'s `initWithImage:style:target:action:` initializer instead.

Comment: yeah when I change the code to `UIBarButtonItem *btn3 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:imageback2 style:nil target:self action:@selector(setColorButtonTapped:)];` it works but now button looks ugly as hell , How can I add my custom style ?

Comment: You can still use a custom view if you want to; just use a regular `UIView` instead of a `UIButton`. Also, you may experiment with different `UIBarButtonItemStyle` settings: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonItemStyle

Comment: @MordFustang you don't need to change your code to UIBarButtonItem instead of using UIButton custom view. Try the below line [self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

UIButton is a view and as such has no view property or instance method.